How do I properly use `source` in a cronjob?
I have - what I think - is a very simple task. Run two commands every 10 minutes.
First, I wrote this function in ~/.bashrc:
chat_login() {
    echo "Running commands at $(date)"
    command1 --role some-role --servername some_server
    source $SOME_PATH/sourceme
    echo "Commands completed at $(date)"
}

Note that I couldn't put it in a script chat_login.sh, because when I run bash /chat_login.sh, the source command had no effect. I found that putting it as a function in ~/.bashrc is the only way to get the source command to work.
Now all I want to do is run chat_login every 10 minutes. This works in the terminal but it fails the second I try to do it with cron, with "chat_login: command not found".
This is the cron setup I've tried. I've already tried playing with the various exports like PATH and BASH_ENV and sourcing the ~/.bashrc file, but I'm unable to get it working.
echo "SHELL=/bin/bash"; echo BASH_ENV="/root/.bashrc"; echo "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"; echo "*/1 * * * * . ~/.bashrc && chat_login >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1"


bash chat_login.sh will invoke a subshell; any variables that are set in the subshell will 'disappear' upon exiting the subshell; the source probably was run with bash chat_login.sh but the results only applied within the scope of the subshell

I have no idea what you mean by This is the cron setup I've tried and that series of echo calls; you should update the question with the complete output from crontab -l

what do you expect a source operation, performed every 10 minutes by cron, to accomplish? what is in $SOME_PATH/sourceme? if the objective is to update some variables in your console session on 10 minute intervals ... you won't accomplish that with cron (hint: cron will start up a completely standalone shell, run the source and then exit the shell; net result is nothing cron does will update variables in your console session); if this doesn't explain your issue then you'll need to update the question with more details on what you're trying to accomplish
